# Why is this JQuery Mobile web page blank?

Tags: jquery-mobile

This JQuery Mobile page is similar to other pages I've created which show up fine.  This is the page in question:

http://moboscope.appspot.com/x/http://slashdot.org/

When I look at the source of the page, it appears to be correct, its just being rendered as a blank page, at least when I test it in Chrome on a Mac.

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: dfp_tile is not defined` in 2 different `document.write()` calls

Comment: @Matt Ball that's the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the browser's JS console:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: dfp_tile is not defined`

in 2 different `document.write()` calls.